# html objects layering with <svg viewBox> (oder of objects)

Tags: css, html, svg

I am currently creating an image that has a svg overlay which interacts via mouseover. My problem is, that I need to assign the title (in < h2>) a link - as well as assign links to the menu items that are created via < button>.

If I assign this link to the first-< a> tag however it supercedes all the links I can assign to the buttons. (every click will lead to the link assigned to the first < a>-tag. I tried using z-index to have the buttons be on top, but my guess is the svg element is on top of the buttons, thus making it impossible to click on the links assigned to the < button> tags.

Any idea on how to assign the title a clickable link as well as have the links on the buttons work? (If I remove the href on the first < a>-tag the links on the buttons work no problem.)

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

```
            <a href="\" data-path-hover="m 181,25.69861 0,0.17222  c 0,0.36942 0,10.69861 -0,10.69861 L 0,50 0,0 181,0 Z">
                <figure>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $stylesheet_directory_uri . '/images/picture.jpg'); ?>"/>
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" fill="#0092AB" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="m 181,170.17857 -56.52362,0.17222 c -45.694531,0.36942 -8.05082,49.60726 -62.096437,47.69861 L 0,218 0,0 181,0 Z"/></svg>
                  <figcaption>      
                        <h2><?php echo $title[$menu_display_item]; ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $slogan[$menu_display_item]; ?></p>
                        <?php foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                            if ($menu_item->menu_item_parent == $menu_display_item) echo '<button style="onclick="window.location=\'' . $url[$key] . '\';">' . $title[$key] . '</button>';
                        } ?>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
```

Comment: Solved it be rewriting everyting to use a < div> element to embed the data-path element instead of the < a> tag. That way < a> can be applied to the < h2> header.